# Oracle comma separated parameter to row and join with other tables

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am using Oracle 10g.
My Scenario:

I am getting some more than 4000 records in a comma separated string('ord0000,ord0001,ord0002,......') as a parameter. I need to compare these values against a table1 and find out the matching recordset.

For that purpose I created a function as below:

```
function get_split_values (

csv_string varchar2
) return split_table pipelined
as
Delimit_String varchar2(32767) := csv_string;
Delimit_index integer;
begin
loop
Delimit_index := instr(delimit_string,',');
if Delimit_index > 0 then
pipe row(substr(delimit_string,1,delimit_index-1));
delimit_string := substr(delimit_string,delimit_index+1);
else
pipe row(delimit_string);
exit;
end if;
end loop;
return;
end get_split_values;
```

Now when I used this function to join with my table1 in a procedure as below:

```
create procedure abc (parameter_csv varchar2,...)
as
begin
open cursor for
select t.col1 from table1 t join table(get_split_values(parameter_csv)) x
on x.column_value = t.col1;
...
end abc;
```

It works fine when the parameter_csv have some around 300 or 400 IDs like('ord0000,ord0001,ord0002,......') but when it contains more that records I got the error
"ORA 01460 : unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested."

I don't understand what raise this error. Any ideas?
OR is there any best way to accomplish this task.

Comment: What is the minimum (approximate) number of entries needed to produce the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially I thought you were overflowing your varchar2(32767) but a quick look at your sample IDs indicates that you shouldn't be maxing out that early(400 ids).

A quick google of the error led me to this forum in OTN: http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=507725&start=15&tstart=0

And to this blog post: http://oraclequirks.blogspot.com/2008/10/ora-01460-unimplemented-or-unreasonable.html

which indicates that this might be an oracle bug

Answer (score 0):

If its a bug with using the PL/SQL procedure, you can just split the string as part of an inline view. Something like.

```
SELECT T.col1
FROM   table1 T
JOIN   (   SELECT  REGEXP_SUBSTR( parameter_csv, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL )  AS id
           FROM    DUAL
           CONNECT BY LEVEL <=
                LENGTH( REGEXP_REPLACE( parameter_csv, '[^,]+', '' ) ) + 1
       ) X
ON     X.id = T.col1;
```

NOTE: Doesn't handle things like duplicate IDs in the the csv, empty values in the csv `,,` etc

Comment: Yeah, it seems this solution breaks if parameter_csv is more than 4000 bytes. So still hitting the limit. Sorry about the bum steer